# rails 3 seems to disable my reference to an mp3 player (SWF and Js)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash

Does rails disable use of a flash .swf file in a rails app by default, and is there a way to make it work?

I am trying to integrate the Wimpy Button MP3 player into pages of my Rails 3 app.

The MP3 player consists of a two files, `wimpy_button.swf` and `wimpy_button.js`. They need to go in the same directory.

I put them both in my /public/javascripts directory (the .js assumes the .swf is in the same directory)

I added the js to my layout (and verified the script src= is in my resulting html files)

```
= javascript_include_tag "wimpy_button.js"
```

(I also tried just hardwiring it with;)

```
<script src="/javacripts/wimpy_button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

On a page, whereever I want an MP3 player button I have this javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
writeWimpyButton("http://example.com/url_to_audio.mp3", "20", "20", "&displayRewindButton=yes");
</script>
```

On my static test pagein /public/testplayer it works fine.

But on any of the active pages, an empty space is where the player icon should be.

I assume the external content is being blocked by some security setting on rails?

Answer (score 0):

Those files don't *need* to be in the same directory. Not sure which version of Rails 3 you're using, but you might be having a fight with the asset pipeline here.

Read more at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Then, put your swf in `app/assets/flash` and your js in `app/assets/javascripts`. Files will be available from your browser at `/flash` and `/javascripts`. You may need to edit the javascript to reference the correct location of your swf file.